# How can I economically store a sparse matrix during the process of element filling?

Tags: c++, memory-management, sparse-matrix

I know there are quite a few good ways to store a sparse matrix without taking up much memory.
But I'm wondering whether there is a good way to store a sparse matrix during the construction of it? Here is the more detailed scenario: the program constructs a sparse matrix by figuring out where to put a non-zero value on each iteration; and since the coordinates of the non-zero value will not be known until runtime, they are totally random and unpredictable.

I'm programming in C++. So is there a way to implement this in C++? Solutions in other languages are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could have 3 parallel list and store rows id in one, column id in the other, value in the third. Once you are done with all entries, you could  reorganize as needed, ex. sort by rows and columns.

What is not described in your question is how do you need/want to represent the sparse matrix in the end? What do you need to do with it? This would affect the representation

Answer (score 1):

std::map might be what you're looking for, it's a key -> value map type. Combine this with std::set, which is a unique collection of elements. So, you could use a map of std::set, like so:

```
std::map<int, std::set<int> > sparseMatrix;

// Add some edges.
sparseMatrix[0].insert(1); // Add an edge from vertex 0 to 1.
sparseMatrix[4].insert(2); // Add an edge from vertex 4 to 2.
sparseMatrix[0].insert(1); // Edge already exists, no data added to the set.
```

This representation lets you represent a directed graph, it's analogous to an edge list. The behaviour of a set also prevents you from having two edges that are 'identical' (a->b and c->d, where a=b and c=d), which is nice, a behaviour you'd get if you used an adjacency matrix. You can iterate al the edges like so:

```
for(std::map<int, std::set<int> >::const_iterator i = sparseMatrix.begin();
    i != sparseMatrix.end();
    ++i)
{
    for(std::set<int>::const_iterator j = i->second.begin();
        j != i->second.end();
        ++j)
    {
        std::cout << "An edge exists from " << i->first << " to " << *j << ".";
    }
}
```

Some links:

- [Set documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/)
- [Map documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)